# List files pattern with "AND" condition in R

Tags: r, list, temporary-files

I want to have a list which includes a character string and which excludes temporary files which include the same character string.
For example:

```
Files <- list.files(pattern= "Coca_cola" & "^[^~]")
```

I found on previous topics on this site that I have to use the "grep" function but I don't know how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the files that start with `"Coca_cola"` which will also drop the temporary files that begin with `"~"`.

```
Files <- list.files(pattern= "^Coca_cola")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
Files <- grepl("Coca_cola", list.files)
Files <- !grepl("~", Files)
```